# unable to reference array outside block

Tags: ios, arrays, url, methods

I have an array called 'venues' that I'm generating in the following method. I'm trying to reuse it in a different method, but every time I try to access it in a different method the array is 'null'. The method is:

```
- (void)startSearchWithString:(NSString *)string {
    [self.lastSearchOperation cancel];
    self.lastSearchOperation = [Foursquare2
        venueSearchNearLocation:@"Chicago" query:nil limit:nil intent:intentCheckin radius:nil categoryId:string
            callback:^(BOOL success, id result){
            if (success) {

                NSDictionary *dic = result;
                NSArray *venuesDic = [dic valueForKeyPath:@"response.venues"];
                self.venues = [SearchVenue placesWithArray:venuesDic];
                NSLog(@"self.venues inside is %@",self.venues);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"%@",result);
            }
        }];
    NSLog(@"self.venues outside is %@",self.venues);
}
```

self.venues inside logs content.
self.venues outside logs (null).
I'm trying __block but without success.

In my .h I have:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *venues;
```

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the array after the callback block has finished?

Comment: When log self.venues inside there's content, but self.venues outside is 'null'. I'm investigating __block but can't get it to register.

Comment: The search you are running is asynchronous. You will see that "outside" logs BEFORE "inside".

Comment: I did understand that inside the block you have content - my question is about timing: are you sure your check outside of the block happens after you put some data in the array inside of the block? The process is asynchronous, so you cant expect the content to be there just after calling startSearchWithString

Comment: Yes you're right 'outside' logs before 'inside'. I didn't catch that. Is it possible to access that array from outside?

Comment: Yes, but not in the way you are doing. You can call another method at the end of the block. But you can't access that array after the block in that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback block is executed asynchronously after `venueSearchNearLocation` has finished.

your log code:

```
NSLog(@"self.venues outside is %@",self.venues);
```

probably gets executed before your callback block and therefore self.venues are still nil.

You must access self.venues after your callback-block has finished.

How you do that really depends on your app. One way of lose coupling is to post a notification after you have set your array.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:
                                      @"VENUES_RECEIVED " object:nil];
```

and in some initializer, you need to listen to that notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(receivedVenus)
                                      name:@"VENUES_RECEIVED" object:nil];
```

and of course you need a method where you can work with your array

```
- (void) receivedVenus
{
    NSLog(@"self.venues outside is %@",self.venues);
}
```

Do not forget to remove your observer (i.e. in dealloc)

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: You don't even need nsnotificationceter. Just call the received method.

Comment: From where? within the block (e.g. after 'NSLog(@"self.venues inside is %@",self.venues);')?

Comment: postNotificationName from within the block after setting your variable

Comment: @Fogmeister That is right: Method can be called from within the block directly (but it "feels" like you are still in the block). I guess you end up calling `[self.tableView reloadData];` or something to update the UI

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
NSArray *venuesDic = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dic valueForKeyPath:@"response.venues"]];
```

Comment: I'm able to get data for self.venues, but the problem is referring to it outside this method. I'll modify the question.

Comment: SearchVenue returns an NSArray?

Comment: If it's "nil" it sounds like you haven't initialized it.
`self.venues = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[SearchVenue placesWithArray:venuesDic]];`

Comment: it still comes up as (null) and I can't get it out of the final brackets '}];'